# I have written a program for Type Conversion (Primitive to class type) . When I am running this on DEV its showing me garbage value

Tags: c++11

```
#include < iostream > 
#include < iomanip >
using namespace::std;
#include < string.h >

  class Human {
    char Name[20];
    int Age;
    float Weight;
    public:

      Human() {
        strcpy(Name, " ");
        Age = Weight = 0;
      }

    Human(int AGE) {
      this - > Age = Age;
    }

    Human(float Weight) {
      this - > Weight = Weight;
    }

    Human(char * s) {
      strcpy(this - > Name, s);
    }

    void GetData() {
      cout << endl << "Enter the name   : ";
      gets(Name);
      cout << endl << "Enter the Age    : ";
      cin >> Age;
      cout << endl << "Enter the Weight :";
      cin >> Weight;
    }

    void Display() {
      cout << endl << "Name   :" << Name;
      cout << endl << "Age    :" << Age;
      cout << endl << fixed << "Weight :" << Weight << " Kg";
    }

  };

int main() {
  Human h1;
  h1 = 23; //It will assign 23 in Age
  h1 = 67.45 f; //It will assign 67.45 in Weight
  h1 = "Jimmy Neutron";
  h1.Display();
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your output values, and what line(s) they come from?
Also you can enclose the entire code block so that it is all displayed as code.

Comment: Name   :Jimmy Neutron
Age    :4194304
Weight :0.000000 Kg

Comment: This is the output which I getting.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here but let me start with the one you asked.

Why is the output like this:

> `Name :Jimmy Neutron Age :4194304 Weight :0.000000 Kg – Udesh`

The reason is every time you assign values like this to your object i.e., `h1`

> `h1 = 23; //It will assign 23 in Age` 
>   `h1 = 67.45f; //It will assign 67.45 in Weight` 
>   `h1 = "Jimmy Neutron";`

This is what is happening behind the scene, `move assignment operator` gets called.

> `h1.operator=(Human(23));` 
>   `h1.operator=(Human(67.4499969f));` 
>   `h1.operator=(Human("Jimmy Neutron"));`

So, the other two arguments get overwritten everytime you write one of this. 
To understand the problem, try using your display function after every assignment statement and see the output.

Now lets come to other issues.

1. Please avoid using `char array` and `char pointer`. We have the wonderful `std::string` for the very same purpose, please use it. IIRC, every major compiler warns about string literal to char * conversion.
2. I do not know if you realized, but the parameter name in one of your constructor that takes `int` is  AGE but you are assigning `age`.
3. Please avoid using deprecated functions - [hint: `gets`]